# Do I have to use attach connection string whenever I connect to a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server. I created a C# application which uses a SQL Server database (automatic attach database) to read/store data using the following connection string:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost; AttachDbFilename=E:\DB\myDB.mdf; trusted_connection=yes")
```

Then I deployed my application into `exe` file. I went to another PC and installed SQL Server and installed my application on it. Now everything works fine but because I am new to SQL Server, I feel that I am attaching the database (`myDB`) in wrong way because it sounds like I attach this database every time I connect to SQL Server.

I run my application for the first time and the database will be attached and next time I run my application it will be attached again (but it is already attached), am I wrong?

My question is: why do I have to attach the database every time I connect to SQL Server using the above connection string? is there another way of attaching it only once? Thank you

Comment: You don't "attach" it over and over again, what you are saying is "take the DB from this file". If you don't specify the file, how do you expect your SqlConnection to know where to look for the DB?

Comment: store the connection string inside of a .config file and access it from there within your application.

Comment: @ cFrozenDeath . I am still confused . before I run my application there was not any database attached in the sql server. and after I run my app I can see the database is newly added (attached ). so it means the database is attached because the connection string specified the database path and "AttachDbFilename" key work made the attach task. Am I wrong .

Comment: @Serena - what version and edition of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Max Vernon I use Express edition V 12.0.2000.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why do I have to attach the database every time I connect to sql
>   server

I am bit confused here with the word *attach*. it's not attaching/detaching at all. What you are doing is specifying the database name and it's path in your connection string and so when you run your application, you app can look into the connection string and can read/write the DB file.

It's same as if you have a local SQL Server installation and connecting to that DB server for getting table data information.

Yes it's true that, it will do multiple read/write based on how many times you are performing DB operations and again whether you are using connected or disconnected ADO.NET architecture.

Comment: @ Rahul . I am still confused . before I run my application there was not any database attached in the sql server. and after I run my app I can see the database is newly added (attached ). so it means the database is attached because the connection string specified the database path and "AttachDbFilename" key work made the attach task. Am I wrong .

Comment: @Serena If the db is already attached, it won't try to attach it again. The AttachDbFilename portion of the string just tells sql server where to find the  database file is the database is not already attached.

Comment: @ Joel Coehoorn. your comment is very convincing. Now I understand :) . Please make your comment as an answer. thank you

Comment: @Serena, as already commented `AttachDbFilename` specifies the DB file to be attached with a local DB instance but that won't happen every time. You might want to read this for more clarification https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx